# Why isn't "citizen" spelled as "citisen" in British English?

Tags: nouns, british-english, orthography, ise-ize

In British English vocabulary, most words with "z" are spelled with "s". For example, "capitalization" is "capitalisation", "industrialization" is "industrialisation".

But for some words, like "citizen", for example, it has a "z" instead of a "s". Why is this like this?

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. It is far too general; Kosmonaut correctly states that it only applies to suffixes (and some at that).

Comment: Why isn't television "televizion" in American English?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'm wondering if your base postulate is chronologically accurate: from my perspective, in American English vocabulary, most words with 's's are replace with 'z's :)

Comment: I went to an Italian restaurant recently. I had pissa and some fissy water. Then I went to the soo to look at the sebra.

Comment: I went to an English restaurant and had ghoti and chips. http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/ling006.html

Comment: @Anonymous Type Zs help when playing scrabble though..

Comment: Just as a point of order, British people aren't citizens, they are subjects.

Comment: @user774, your point of order is out of order. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_nationality_law and also http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/britishcitizenship/ .

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a suffix that is written only as *-ize* in American English and often *-ise* in British English (but not always, as ShreevatsaR points out in the comments).  This suffix attaches to a large number of words, thus the s/z alternation shows up in a large number of words.  *Citizen* does not have the *-ize/-ise* suffix.

Comment: It would be redundant for me to add another answer, but let me note that both -ise and -ize are prevalent in British English. Wikipedia has two related articles: [the one on spelling differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29) and [Oxford spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling).

Comment: Nor does 'analyse', but Americans resolutely spell it 'analyze' (or do they also write 'analize' sometimes?).

Comment: *Analyze* does have the *-ize/-ise* suffix, just a different spelling.  From the OED: "On Greek analogies the vb. would have been *analysize*, Fr. *analysiser*, of which *analyser* was practically a shortened form, since, though following the analogy of pairs like *annexe*, *annexe-r*, it rested chiefly on the fact that by form-assoc. it appeared already to belong to the series of factitive vbs. in *-iser*, Eng. **-ize** ... to which in sense it belonged. Hence from the first it was commonly written in Eng. *analyze*, the spelling accepted by Johnson, and historically quite defensible."

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the etymology of **citizen** is linked to that of **denizen**.

Comment: They aren't etymologically related, but the spelling of citizen was, in fact, influenced by *denizen* — only not the "z" part.  [It used to be *citezein*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=citizen).