# "s" vs. "z" in BE vs. AE

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, ise-ize

I have trouble understanding why some words change "s"-es to "z"-s from BE to AE and some not. For example:

- analyse -> analyze
- characterise -> characterize
- hypnotise -> hypnotize

But:

- compromise -> compromise

Is there any rule to this?

Slightly related: [Why isn't "citizen" spelled as "citisen" in British English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/why-isnt-citizen-citisen-in-british-english)

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/707/8019 (and others)

Comment: Seemingly irrelevant, there is the fascinating [Barthes S/Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/Z). Not to give anything away, but this may explain a lot about the perceived cultural differences between the US and the UK.

Comment: Oxford University Press and Cambridge University Press use the _-ize_ spelling where it corresponds to the Greek etymology (see Andrew Leach’s answer).  So, it is not exactly BE versus AE (though the division is broadly accurate).

Comment: That isn't even slightly related, because BE came first. British spelling comes from wherever it came from, and 's'/'z' accordingly; American spelling changes many of those to the more phonetic 'z'.

Comment: @OllieFord BrE did not 'come first'; rather, when the Americans left we spoke and wrote the same way, and after they left each started diverging from the original point. In any case, the *z* is recent in *-yse* but not *-ize*, *-yse* from Greek *-lysis* and *-ize* from Greek *-izein*, Latin *-izare*. The spelling *-ise* comes from French *-iser*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ize) contains useful information.

> ### *-ize*
>
> suffix forming verbs, M.E. *-isen,* from O.Fr. *-iser,* from L.L. *-izare,* from Gk. *-izein.* English picked up the French form, but partially reverted to the correct Greek *-z-* spelling from late 16c. In Britain, despite the opposition (at least formerly) of OED, *Encyclopaedia Britannica,* the “Times of London,” and Fowler, *-ise* remains dominant. Fowler thinks this is to avoid the difficulty of remembering the short list of common words not from Greek which must be spelled with an *-s-* (e.g. advertise, devise, surprise).

That last list includes *compromise* too, as that does not have a Greek root.

The one I’ve had most contact with is *baptise/baptize* which comes directly from the Greek *baptizein* and presumably should be spelled with *z*.

As someone with an interest in letterforms, I've always found **z** an anomalous letter (the thick stroke goes in the wrong direction) and I far prefer the appearance of these words spelled with an **s**. That may also be a contributory factor (as well as Fowler’s “difficulty”), even if only subliminally.

The OED<sup>[[paywalled link]](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/100447#eid40534583)</sup> provides this etymological note on the *‑ize* suffix, and on how they use that suffix in that dictionary:

> **Etymology:** Cognate with French *‑ise‑r*, Italian *‑izare*, Spanish
>   *‑izar*, < late Latin *‑izāre*, *‑īzāre*, < Greek *‑ίζειν*, formative of
>   verbs.
>
> > The Greek verbs were partly intransitive, as *βαρβαρίζειν* to play the 
> >     barbarian, act or speak as a barbarian, side with the barbarians,
> >     *τυραννίζειν* to side with the tyrants, partly transitive as *καθαρίζειν*
> >     to purify, clean, *θήσαυρίζειν* to treasure up.  Those formed on national,
> >     sectarian, or personal names were primarily intransitive, as *Ἀττικίζειν*
> >     to Atticize in manners, to speak Attic, *Φιλιππίζειν* to act or speak for 
> >     Philip, to philippize, *Ἑλληνίζειν* to ‘do’ the Greek, act as a Greek,
> >     speak Greek, Hellenize; also, to make Greek.  A few words of this form
> >     connected with or used in early Christianity, were latinized already in the 
> >     3rd or 4th cent. by Christian writers: such were *βαπτίζειν* *baptizāre*,
> >     *εὐαγγελίζειν* *euangelizāre*, *κατηχίζειν* *catechizāre*, *σκανδαλίζειν*
> >     *scandalizāre*, *ἀναθηματίζειν* *anathēmatizāre*, *χριστιανίζειν*
> >     *christiānizāre*, *ἰουδαίζειν* *iūdaizāre*.  Others continued to be formed
> >     both in ecclesiastical and philosophical use, e.g.  *canōnizāre*,
> >     *daemonizāre*, *syllogizāre* (Boethius *Aristot. Anal.*); and this became
> >     established as the normal form for the latinizing of Greek verbs, or the 
> >     formation of verbs upon Greek analogies.  In medieval Latin and the modern
> >     languages these have been formed also on Latin or modern national names,
> >     and the use has been extended to the formation of verbs from Latin
> >     adjectives or nouns.  This practice probably began first in French; in
> >     modern French the suffix has become *‑iser*, alike in words from Greek, as
> >     *baptiser*, *évangéliser*, *organiser*, and those formed after them from
> >     Latin, as *civiliser*, *cicatriser*, *humaniser*.  Hence, some have used
> >     the spelling *‑ise* in English, as in French, for all these words, and some
> >     prefer *‑ise* in words formed in French or English from Latin elements,
> >     retaining *‑ize* for those formed < Greek elements.  But the suffix itself,
> >     whatever the element to which it is added, is in its origin the Greek
> >     *‑ιζειν*, Latin *‑izāre*; and, as the pronunciation is also with *z*, there
> >     is no reason why in English the special French spelling should be followed,
> >     in opposition to that which is at once etymological and phonetic.  In this
> >     Dictionary the termination is uniformly written *‑ize*.  (In the Greek
> >     *‑ιζ‑*, the *i* was short, so originally in Latin, but the double consonant
> >     *z* (= *dz*, *ts*) made the syllable long; when the *z* became a simple
> >     consonant, /‑idz/ became *īz*, whence English /‑aɪz/.)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/are-the-endings-zation-and-sation-interchangeable appears to be a duplicate but the Greek root is only mentioned in one comment.

Comment: Just watched an Inspector Morse where the ise/ize issue was prevalent in the plot. That one of the suspects did not use the Oxford ize !

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I just now discovered that I have flagged this fantastic post as Not An Answer. I'm sorry, I meant to mark the "Azprin"  answer, and I must have clicked the flag on yours instead, not noticing what I had done until I went vaingloriously to check my "useful flags" queue. Can a flag be reversed, or is it a permanent mark?

Comment: @Conrado No, unfortunately a comment flag is permanent. Mods can decline it for you since your comment indicates it's the right thing to do; but I'll leave it to my colleagues rather than act on my own post. Thank you for the comment (which can/will be removed once the flag is dealt with).

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the great answer from @AndrewLeach, the answer quoted EtymOnline with

> Fowler thinks this is to avoid the difficulty of remembering the short list of common words not from Greek which must be spelled with an -s- (e.g. advertise, devise, surprise).

So, I went in search for the short list and found the following from [Lexico](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825044143/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/ize-ise-or-yse), which also adds a bit more to the mix when reading the whole page

> In both American and British English, there is a small set of verbs that must always be spelled with *-ise* at the end. The main reason for this is that, in these words, *-ise* is part of a longer word element rather than being a separate ending in its own right. For example: *-cise* (meaning 'cutting) in the word excise; *-prise* (meaning 'taking') as in surprise; or *-mise* (meaning 'sending') in promise.

The list they provided is as follows:

- advertise
- compromise
- exercise
- revise
- advise
- despise
- improvise
- supervise
- apprise
- devise
- incise
- surmise
- chastise
- disguise
- prise (meaning ‘open’)
- surprise
- comprise
- excise
- promise
- televise

> There are also a few verbs which always end in *-yse* in British English.

- analyse
- catalyse
- electrolyse
- paralyse
- breathalyse
- dialyse
- hydrolyse
- psychoanalyse

> In American English, they are all spelled with the ending *-yze*